# "No data available in Table" even data exists within the table

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

Why does my table displays the error "No data available in the Table" and shows "Showing 0 of 0 entries" below. [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igDLq.png)

I have no idea why does this happen. I'm using mysqli_fetch_assoc to get the data from my query.

```
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
        <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
        Data Table
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ref. No.</th>
                        <th>Date/Time</th>
                        <th>Line No.</th>
                        <th>Optr. Name</th>
                        <th>Weight</th>
                        <th>Moisture</th>
                        <th>Product ID</th>
                        <th>Item Code</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_refno']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_weight_dt']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_line_id']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_opt_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_weight']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_moisture']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_prod_id']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_prod_code']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?> 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated yesterday at 11:59 PM</div>
</div>


<tbody>
  <?php while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $rows['mb_refno']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['mb_weight_dt']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['mb_line_id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['mb_opt_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['mb_weight']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['mb_moisture']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['mb_prod_id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows['mb_prod_code']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>  
</tbody>
```

Comment: You need to perform a database query first, before you can read the result. If you in fact do perform a query first, please include it in your code example.

Comment: I think that the table structure is of Data table is not correct. First you are displaying data from database in <thead></thead> and after that you are using same resource and while loop in <tbody></tbody>.
I think that after using resource one time in a loop empties it.

Comment: use `num_rows` before using while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI dataTables requires a well formed table. It must contain `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags, otherwise it throws this error. Also, check to make sure all your rows including header row have the same number of columns.

```
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header">
        <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
        Data Table
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ref. No.</th>
                        <th>Date/Time</th>
                        <th>Line No.</th>
                        <th>Optr. Name</th>
                        <th>Weight</th>
                        <th>Moisture</th>
                        <th>Product ID</th>
                        <th>Item Code</th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                    <?php while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_refno']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_weight_dt']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_line_id']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_opt_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_weight']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_moisture']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_prod_id']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['mb_prod_code']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?> 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated yesterday at 11:59 PM</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you I only forgot the </thead> it fixed my error and show the results 4 out of 4 thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can only read the results of your query with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` once. If you attempt to read it again, you get the error message. If you really want to read the result of the query twice, you must first do the query again.